# Selecting a particular image from image array by mouse over action

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

How  can I select the img which has the mouse cursor on it from the img array below ? I mean I want to be able to do changes on the image, hide for example or make some interaction with it.

```
var images = [];

function preload() {
  for (var i = 0; i< 18; i++) {
    images[i] = loadImage("img/img" + i + ".jpg");
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 900); 
  background(0);
  preload();
}

function draw() {
  var i = 0;
  for ( var y= 0; y < height; y=y+150) {
    for ( var x =0; x < width; x=x+150) {
      image(images[i % images.length], x, y );
      i++
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking the mouseX and mouseY position then calculating how many images across and how many images and how many images down you are then find the index of that image by adding the position across to the position down times by the amount of images in the row. Example:

```js
var images = [];
var selected;

function preload() {
  for (var i = 0; i< 18; i++) {
    images[i] = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/Google_Chrome_for_Android_Icon_2016.svg/150px-Google_Chrome_for_Android_Icon_2016.svg.png");
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 900); 
  background(0);
  preload();
}

function draw() {
  var i = 0;
  if (mouseX < width & mouseY < height) {
      selected = Math.floor(mouseX / 150) + Math.floor(mouseY / 150) * Math.floor(height / 150);
  } else {
      selected = -1;
      // not found as out side of canvas
  }
  console.log("selected image: ", selected);
  for ( var y= 0; y < height; y=y+150) {
    for ( var x =0; x < width; x=x+150) {
      image(images[i % images.length], x, y );
      i++
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.3.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Check the console and it will be printing the selected image which you can then use to change that image as you with.

Comment: but the calculated surface is beyond the canvas this way, i mean it also logs the locations which are out of canvas area. Is there a way to map it ?

Comment: See my edit that should cover it :) hope this is acceptable

Comment: wow, thank you, mapping it was easier than I thought but, still couldn't do it :P maybe I am not meant for programming ^^ thank you again.

Comment: No problem you'll get the hang of it :) Just fyi if you're interested in p5.js you might want to look at Dan Shiffman's video, https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman they're great! Don't mean to side track you or anything

Comment: actually his videos helped me to create the array in the first place :) I am quite new in field of programming so his videos are gold to me :)